# Computing the subset giving the minimum standard deviation in an array

Tags: algorithm, matlab, combinations

Let us have a vector of size `N`. For example:

```
x = rand(N,1)
```

I want to compute the minimum standard deviation of a subset of length `K` in the vector.

When `N` and `K` are small, it is easy to find the best subset since I can use `nchoosek(N,K)` to enumerate all possible subsets. But when the values of `N` and `K` are larger than let's say `N=50` and `K=25`, `nchoosek` fails to compute the combinations since the size of the possible subsets are huge.

I wonder if there is a better algorithm to compute the subset that gives the smallest standard deviation in an array efficiently. For example via dynamic programming. Any ideas?

**Update**:

I've implemented it in a loop aftter the answers and compared to the combinatorial solution. The results are always the same but the speed gain are unprecedented.

```
n = 20;
k = 10;
x = rand(n,1);
C = nchoosek(x, k);

tic
mins = realmax;
for i = 1:size(C,1)
    s = std(C(i,:));
    if s < mins
        mins = s;
        bestC = C(i,:);
    end
end
toc

tic
[x2, j] = sort(x);
mins2 = realmax;
for i = 1:(n-k+1)
    s = std(x2(i:(i+k-1)));
    if s < mins2
        mins2 = s;
        idx = j((i:(i+k-1)));
    end
end
toc

if mins == mins2
    'Equal'
end
```

gives

```
Elapsed time is 7.786579 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.002068 seconds.

ans =

Equal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the array and then compute this in one pass with rolling window of length `K`.

I'm sure this will give you the right answer, will think if I can prove it.

Hand-wavey argument, with a possible gap in logic in the "extend this" part:

Consider an element `x` from your list. Let's try and find the minimum standard deviation of a set of size 2 containing this element. We'll get this by choosing `x` and the closest element to `x`. Extend this to `k` elements and we'll get a set that is a contiguous part of the sorted list that contains `x`. To pick the smallest subset of `k` elements (i.e for any `x`) we therefore just have to iterate over the sorted list as described before.

Comment: I think you are correct, and I think the solution I posted finds it using `conv` instead of a matlab loop (which may or may not be faster). But I also can't prove it.

Comment: @Dan have posted a justification but I think it's incomplete.

Comment: This inductive method proves that adding the closest element leads to the minimal increase in volatility. However, it does not say that it will give you a set of size n+1 with minimum volatility. Obviously this is not the case as starting with an outlier will definitely not have to lead you to a minimum volatility set. This is countered by starting at every point, but it is not yet proven here whether this is sufficient.-- Intuitively it does feel like this answer is right so I will give you my vote in the hope that it is correct.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin you are right it is not watertight. I think this may be a better approach for a proof. Step 1: Show that for any non-consecutive subset, we can reduce the variance by replacing an appropriate (e.g. the smallest or largest) element with an element in one of the "holes". Step 2: Applying Step 1 repeatedly we see that any minimal variance subset must be a contiguous part of the sorted list. Of course the fiddly part is proving Step 1. But this approach would avoid the issues that you pointed out.