# minimize variance of k integers from n ordered integers

Tags: algorithm

Given a series of n integers and a number k, n>k, what's the solution of minimizing the variance of k new integers? You may add up any successive integers to a new integer and thus reduce n integers to k integers.

Here is an example. Given n=4, k=2, the series of integers are 4,4,1,1. The solution is 4,6 instead of 8,2 or 9,1.

I have come up with a greedy algorithm which goes like this: for every possible new integers, minimize the absolute value of the difference of this integer and the average of all the integers. But this won't work in some cases. Is there any efficient algorithm works?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computing the subset giving the minimum standard deviation in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143843/computing-the-subset-giving-the-minimum-standard-deviation-in-an-array)

Comment: @YXD There's definitely a duplicate, but that's not it.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat you're right. I misread the question. I have retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variance of a random variable X is E[(X - E[X])^2]. Here X is a random element of the output list. We know that E[X] is equal to the sum of the input numbers divided by k, so this objective is equivalent to the sum of (x - sum/k)^2 over output values x. This can be accomplished by slightly modifying a word wrap algorithm: [Word wrap to X lines instead of maximum width (Least raggedness)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426017/word-wrap-to-x-lines-instead-of-maximum-width-least-raggedness)